# Hadamard's Formula Proof Help

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

Hadamard's Formula says that for a power series, $\frac{1}{R} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \sup \sqrt[n]{|a_n|}$ implies that $\sum a_n z^n$ is absolutely convergent on $D_R$ and uniformly convergent on $D_r$ for $r < R$.

The proof I am reading shows the absolute convergence by choosing $r$ such that $0 \leq |z| < r < R$ and then since that eventually $|a_n|^\frac{1}{n} < \frac{1}{r}$, this implies $|a_n z^n| < (\frac{|Z|}{r})^n$ showing that our series is dominated by the convergent geometric series, and is therefore absolutely convergent on $D_r$.

It then says that since $r$ can be made arbitrarily close to $R$, this shows absolute convergence for $D_R$. It is't obvious to me that this is the case. Why is it true?

And why can't we make the same claim at the end of the uniform convergence portion of the proof and just say $r$ can be brought close to $R$ and therefore it is uniformly convergent on $D_R$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $z\in D_R$, there is some $r<R$ such that $z\in D_r$ since $r$ can be made arbitrarily close to $R$. Thus $\sum a_nz^n$ converges absolutely, since $\sum a_nz^n$ converges absolutely on all of $D_r$.

The same idea cannot be applied to the case of uniform convergence since absolute convergence concerns *particular* values of $z$, while uniform convergence concerns *all* values of $z$ in $D_R$ at the same time. There is no $r<R$ such that $z\in D_r$ for all $z\in D_R$.